# Why does Google Search Console dislike my C# ASP.NET Core MVC routes?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, sitemap, google-search-console

I've just deployed a C# ASP.NET Core 8.0 MVC web app to Azure.

I have a `Sitemap.xml` file, as you can see here:

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url>
<loc>Home/Index</loc>
<lastmod>2024-01-30</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>About/Index</loc>
<lastmod>2024-01-30</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>About/Guide</loc>
<lastmod>2024-01-30</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>/About/FAQs</loc>
<lastmod>2024-01-30</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>/About/Roadmap</loc>
<lastmod>2024-01-30</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>/About/Terms</loc>
<lastmod>2024-01-30</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>/About/Privacy</loc>
<lastmod>2024-01-30</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>/About/GDPR</loc>
<lastmod>2024-01-30</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>/Support/ContactUs</loc>
<lastmod>2024-01-30</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>/Support/Troubleshooting</loc>
<lastmod>2024-01-30</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>/Blog</loc>
<lastmod>2024-01-30</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>/rss</loc>
<lastmod>2024-01-30</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>/Account/SignUp</loc>
<lastmod>2024-01-30</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>/Account/LogIn</loc>
<lastmod>2024-01-30</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>/Account/ForgotPassword</loc>
<lastmod>2024-01-30</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>/</loc>
<lastmod>2024-01-30</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>
/blog/Real-time-UK-FIRE-Calculator-Release-Version-1
</loc>
<lastmod>2024-01-30</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
</urlset>
```

I submitted my `Sitemap.xml` URL to Google Search Console, to begin getting the website index, only to receive the following list of errors, whereby Google states that they dislike urls such as "/", or "About/Guide".

```
Sitemap can be read, but has errors
Invalid URL
17 instances
This is not a valid URL. Please correct it and resubmit.
Examples
URL:
Home/Index
Line 3
Parent tag:
url
Tag:
loc
URL:
About/Index
Line 9
Parent tag:
url
Tag:
loc
URL:
About/Guide
Line 15
Parent tag:
url
Tag:
loc
```

Any ideas why this is? Or what I should do?

Help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: does it require a full url, not just a fragment? yes it does: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/sitemaps/build-sitemap#xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should modify your XML sitemap to look like this:

```xml
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url><loc>https://example.com/Home/</loc></url>
<url><loc>https://example.com/About/</loc></url>
<url><loc>https://example.com/About/Guide</loc></url>
...
</urlset>
```

- `<loc>` elements should contain fully qualified URLs (with `https://` and the domain name)
- `Index` should **never** appear in your URLs.  Index documents power the directory.  They are meant to be hidden from the URL and only used in the web server back end.
- Google ignores `lastmod`, `changefreq` and `priority` so you should just omit them. Especially if you are not setting them accurately.

Comment: By Index documents, you mean that I shouldn't have a url of "https://www.example.com/home/index"...and instead it should be "https://www.example.com/home" ?

Comment: correct, although you probably shouldn't have "home" in the URL either.  The URL for the home page should just be `https://example.com/`